# Use number of days column to update the date field in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Hello My dataframe "finaldatadf" looks like the below. I am trying to update my delivery date my adding days in the transit column (business days) to the shipdate field.

ShipDate & Deliverydate are datetime and transit is of type int

[image: ShipDate DeliveryDate Transit 5/27/2021 5/31/2021 2 5/27/2021 ? 3]

There are rows where the DeliveryDate field is empty. So what I'm trying to do is update the DeliveryDate only for those rows where the DeliveryDate is empty with the below formula :

DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate + n business days
where n = value in the transit column

I only want to update the columns where the delivery dates are not already populated. I want to keep the data the same for the rows that already has the delivery date.
Output :

[image: ShipDate DeliveryDate Transit 5/27/2021 5/31/2021 2 5/27/2021 6/1/2021 3]

Comment: `DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate + ...` is not possible. How to obtain 2021-06-01? 2021-05-31 + BD(2) = 2021-06-02 and 2021-05-31 + BD(3) = 2021-06-03.

Comment: It's business days @Corralien. 6/1 is 5/27 + 3 business days since 5/29 and 5/30 are weekend.

Comment: My bad... I didn't see the first column :)

Comment: Thanks you guys that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`BDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BDay.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-bday) from `pandas.tseries.offsets`:

```
m = df['DeliveryDate'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'DeliveryDate'] = df[m].apply(
    lambda x: x['ShipDate'] + BDay(x['Transit']),
    axis=1
)
```

```
    ShipDate DeliveryDate  Transit
0 2021-05-27   2021-05-31        2
1 2021-05-27   2021-06-01        3
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ShipDate': ['5/27/2021', '5/27/2021'],
    'DeliveryDate': ['5/31/2021', None],
    'Transit': [2, 3]
})
df['ShipDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ShipDate'])
df['DeliveryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DeliveryDate'])

m = df['DeliveryDate'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'DeliveryDate'] = df[m].apply(
    lambda x: x['ShipDate'] + BDay(x['Transit']),
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Henry. That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Convert columns to `datetime64` if not already done:

```py
df["ShipDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ShipDate"])
df["DeliveryDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DeliveryDate"])
```

```
offset_bd = lambda x: x["ShipDate"] + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(x["Transit"])
df["DeliveryDate"] = df["DeliveryDate"].fillna(df.apply(offset_bd, axis=1))
```

```py
    ShipDate DeliveryDate  Transit
0 2021-05-27   2021-05-31        2
1 2021-05-27   2021-06-01        3
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. That was very helpful!